# why custom svg cursor is vanishing after certain value of height and width is reached

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mouse-cursor

I want to display a custom circular shape as cursor whose sizes are dynamic.

general logic i'm following is, if `radius = some value` and svg `height and width` is `twice the radius`
i.e for `r="64"` `--->` `width="128" height="128"`

**Problem statement**

- I found `128` is the threshold `height and width`.
- if it is increased just by one i.e `129` then cursor will no longer appear.

**How to increase cursor side beyond `128` i.e radius is beyond `64`?**

see below code example,

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
one.style.cursor = `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="%23FF0000" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="64" fill="yellow" /></svg>') 32 32, auto`;  

var two = document.getElementById('two');
two.style.cursor = `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="%23FF0000" width="129" height="129" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="64" fill="yellow" /></svg>') 32 32, auto`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="one" style="padding: 50px; background-color:green">one</div>
    <div id="two" style="padding: 50px; background-color:red">two</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that is likely a restriction applied by either the browser or the OS.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#cursor: _"If an operating system is incapable of rendering a cursor above a given size, cursors larger than that size must be shrunk to within the OS-supported size bounds, while maintaining the cursor image’s natural aspect ratio, if any."_

Comment: [cursor - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#usage_notes) says: "Although the specification does not define any size limitations for cursor, individual user agents may choose to do so. Cursor changes using images which are outside the size range supported by the browser will generally just be ignored."

Comment: An alternative could be to hide the cursor and then display the image on top of everything else at the position of the hidden cursor. Listen for the mousemove even.

Comment: Please read this [Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#limitations): _In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms._